# Obter os dois objetos de um array

Tags: json, laravel

Recebo uma requisição com o seguinte objeto:

```
{
 "member_id": 1,
 "lista": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "member_id": 1,
  "instituicao": "Teste Fund",
  "data_inicio": "2018-04-25T06:00:00.000Z",
  "data_termino": "2018-04-25T06:00:00.000Z",
  "cidade": "Sao Paulo",
  "estado": "SP",
  "serie": "5",
  "curso": null,
  "tipo": "fundamental"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "member_id": 1,
  "instituicao": "Teste Sup",
  "data_inicio": "2018-04-25T06:00:00.000Z",
  "data_termino": "2018-04-25T06:00:00.000Z",
  "cidade": "Belo Horizonte",
  "estado": "MG",
  "serie": null,
  "curso": "Teologia",
  "tipo": "superior"
}
 ]
}
```

O member_id estou conseguindo obter, porém o 'Lista' sempre chega vázio.

Método que envio a requisição:

```
 public function update(AcademicoRequest $request)
{
    $res = $request->all();
    if ( $request->has('member_id') ) {
        $dados_academicos = DB::table('academicos')->where('member_id', $request->member_id)->orderby('id')->get()->pluck('id')->unique()->all();

        $this->destroy($dados_academicos);
    }
    $lista = $res['lista'];

    foreach($lista as $value) {
        Academico::create($value);
    }

    $result = array(
        'message' => 'Os dados foram alterados com sucesso! ',
        'data' => index($res->member_id),
        'success' => true,
    );
    return response()->json($result);
}
```

Comment: Qual o retorno de `var_dump($res)`?

Comment: Vem um [] vazio.

Comment: Então qual é o retorno de `var_dump($request)`?

Comment: O retorno é enorme, não dá para compartilhar.

Comment: Já tentou `$request->input('key');` ou `$request->json('key')` ?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, utilizando $request->json('key') consegui obter. Obrigado. Posta a resposta! ^^